# Is there a global document frame count?

Tags: javascript

Essentially I have some custom controls like sliders and dropdown menus with cool effects.

They rely heavily on getBoundingClientRect to allow for flexibility in CSS, things like changing paddings/font sizes/whatever without throwing off how the control works.

The downside is, getBoundingClientRect is a bit expensive to call so often and due to the way the code is laid out, it sometimes gets called multiple times for the same element in the same frame.

Now I could try and call it only once for each element but it would be a pile of messy if-then sphagetti. Alternatively, I figured I could store the value on a global frame # basis.

Is there a global document frame # available in js?

Comment: There is a [*window.frames*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-frames) object which has a *length* property. Also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames).

Comment: @RobG that's for iframes in the document

Comment: Perhaps "*a global document frame #*" needs to be clarified?

Comment: @robg only if you exclusively read the last line of the post

Comment: Not sure what your frame counter will help you with... But note that gBCR is expensive, the first time it is called on any element after something has changed in the layout. This means that if you call forty times gBCR on various elements in the same frame, without changing anything to the layout, then only the first call will really be expansive (since it needs a complete reflow of the page in order to get the one value you requested).

Comment: @Kaiido ah well in that case I guess its already doing what I'm trying to do which is cache the layout

Comment: There is also "*… I figured I could store the value on a global frame # basis…*". If you'er referring to some other kind of frame then maybe you should add some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The question is still open but I found a way to implement my own frame counter

```js
window.render_stats = {
 "total_frames" : 0,
};

(function() {
 render_stats.total_frames += 1;
 requestAnimationFrame(arguments.callee);
})();
```